# OnUpgrade добавление новых полей SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Суть проблемы такова: имеется приложение с БД, уже установленное на разных смартфонах, и теперь возникла необходимость добавить еще 2 поля в базе данных. При это методе OnUpgrade ничего не работает, при записи в новую бд выдаёт ошибку

> (1) table mytab has no column named apnds

```
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE mytab ADD COLUMN apnds, gprsds INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
        }
    }
```

Если удалить приложение и установить уже с новой версией - всё записывает, но мне надо сохранить старые записи в БД
Код таблицы: (apnds и gprsds в предыдущей версии таблицы небыло)

```
 private static final String DB_CREATE =
        "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                COLUMN_NAME + " text, " +
                COLUMN_TESTTIME + " text, " +
                COLUMN_IP1 + " text, " +
                COLUMN_SOCKET1 + " text, " +
                COLUMN_IP2 + " text, " +
                COLUMN_SOCKET2 + " text, " +
                COLUMN_APN + " text, " +
                COLUMN_GPRS + " text, " +
                COLUMN_APN_DS + " text, " +
                COLUMN_GPRS_DS + " text " +
                ");";
```

Comment: если же я не ошибаюсь - "has no" это не имеет строчки

Comment: измените версию БД в классе где вы обрашаетес в базу. видимо оно осталось старой

Comment: Версию БД менял

Comment: Прошу прощения за опечатку. Старый комментарий удалил. Данная ошибка говорит о том, что этого столбца нет, а точнее не выполнился запрос на изменение таблицы.

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что добавление столбцов в таблицу не произошло. Причина, скорее всего, ошибка в синтаксисе соответствующего запроса.

В SQLite `ADD COLUMN` может добавлять только одну колонку. Поэтому, если хотите добавить больше пишите сразу несколько запросов. Например:

```
ALTER TABLE mytab ADD COLUMN apnds TEXT;
ALTER TABLE mytab ADD COLUMN gprsds INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
```

Также при добавлении колонок лучше всё-таки указывать тип данных.